# Wordpress Stylesheets and some Javascript files do not work

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2

[image]

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance, and I have hosted multiple sites using Apache. Other sites are working, but when I install WordPress, it looks like this.. Someone please support me or explain why this is happening. It's showing some http and https errors as well.

I have configured my wordpress.conf file like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName wordpress.foodiebell.app
   ServerAlias www.wordpress.foodiebell.app
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
   
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteOptions inherit
   RewriteRule \.(svn|git)(/)?$ - [F]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wordpress.foodiebell\.app [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.wordpress.foodiebell.app/$1 [L,R]
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
     Require all granted
     AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
     Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also, i created .htaccess file inside the wordpress root like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

my domain name is [wordpress.foodiebell.app](https://wordpress.foodiebell.app)